# $\int_{D^2}f^*\omega = 0$ for any smooth map $f$ that maps $\partial D^2\to S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

> Consider the differential $2$-from $\omega = {dx\wedge dy\over x^2+y^2}$ on $X =\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$. Prove that, for the unit disk $D^2$ and for any smooth map $f:D^2\to X$ which sends the boundray circle to the unit circle $S^1$,
> $$\int_{D^2}f^*(\omega) =0.$$

Since $df^*(\omega) = f^*(d\omega) =0$, $f^*\omega$ is closed form on $D^2$ so exact as $D^2$ is contractible. Hence, $f^*\omega$ is exact on $D^2$. So, there is a $1$-form $\alpha$ on $D^2$ such that $f^*\omega = d\alpha$. So the desired result is equivalent to showing $\int_{S^1}\alpha =0$. So far I didn't use anything about $\omega$ and $f$ maps $S^1$ to $S^1$. Could you give any hints?

Comment: You can’t integrate $dx\wedge dy$ on $S^1$, the degrees do not match! Also, $f^{\ast}(\omega)$ should be $d\alpha$ for some *1-form* $\alpha$ on $D^2$.

Comment: @Aphelli Ah, I see. So $f^*\omega = d\alpha$ for some $1$-form $\alpha$ on $D^2$. If $\iota:S^1\hookrightarrow D^2$ then $\iota^*d\alpha = \iota^*f^*\omega = (f\circ\iota)^*\omega= dx\wedge dy$. Then
$$\int_{D^2}f^*\omega =\int_{S^1}\alpha = \int_{S^1}\iota^*\alpha = \int_{D^2}d\iota^*\alpha =\int_{D^2}dx\wedge dy.$$
but this is not zero.

Comment: $i^{\ast}d\alpha$ is a $2$-form on $S^1$ so is zero! Note also that $di^{\ast}\alpha$ is not defined as a $2$-form over $D^2$.

Comment: @Aphelli Hmmm ok so nothing is progressed so far... Could you give any hint for this problem?

Comment: Poincaré lemma gives a **1-form** $\alpha$ **on $D^2$** such that $f^*\omega = d\alpha$, not a $3$-form on $X$.

Comment: @Didier Yes I used that to conclude $f^*\omega$ is exact. I'm trying to use the explicitly given $\omega$ and the fact that $f|_{S^1}:S^1\to S^1$ but no progress so far.

Comment: @onepotatotwopotato Sorry, I edited my comment while you were writing yours and now, it is completely different

Comment: @onepotatotwopotato Any assumption on how the restriction of $f$ to $S^1$ is? Is it the identity map, surjective or anything?

Comment: @Didier No, nothing. The question is from a past exam so there might be a typo. *Any smooth map $f$ which sends the boundary of the disc to the unit circle*.

Comment: @onepotatotwopotato that wasn't obvious at all! I guess it's not the very first question of the exam, right?

Comment: @Didier No, it is the very last problem of the exam. Thank you for the solution. I first thought there're some typos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to show that $\omega$ is already exact, and that the $1$-form $\beta$ such that $\omega = d\beta$ can be chosen to vanish on $S^1$.
It can be done by using polar coordinates.
Writing $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, we have
$$
\omega = \frac{rdr\wedge d\theta}{r^2} = \frac{1}{r}dr\wedge d\theta = d\left(\ln (r) d\theta\right).
$$
It follows that $\omega = d\beta$, with
$$
\beta = \frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)\frac{xdy - ydx}{x^2+y^2}.
$$
Here, I have used that $d\theta = \frac{xdy - ydx}{x^2+y^2}$.

From the naturality of the pull-back,, $f^*\omega = f^*d\beta = d(f^*\beta)$, and Stokes formula yields
$$
\int_{D^2}f^*\omega = \int_{\partial D^2}i^*\left(f^*\beta\right).
$$
with $i\colon \partial D^2 \to D^2$ the inclusion map.
On $S^1$, $\beta=0$ since $\ln(x^2+y^2)=\ln 1=0$.
Because $f\circ i$ takes values in $S^1$, we have $i^*(f^*\beta) = (f\circ i)^*\beta=0$.
The result follows.